# What is the Java equivalent of a JavaScript callback?

Tags: java, javascript

I am experienced in JavaScript but new to Java. I am trying to figure out how to pass a function as a parameter of another function. In JavaScript this would like the block in Figure 1.

**Figure 1**

```
function fetchData(url, callback) {

    // Do ajax request and fetch data from possibly slow server

    // When the request is done, call the callback function
    callback(ajaxResponse);

}
```

Is there a similar way of doing this in Java? I have searched the internets, but found little that is helpful on a novice level.

Comment: Until Java 8, this is only possible using interfaces.

Comment: Is there perhaps a different pattern then for solving this?

Comment: Send an interface `MyInterface myInterface` that contains a `callback` method, then instead of `callback(ajaxResponse);` do `myInterface.callback(ajaxResponse);`.

Comment: Also see http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html for a more extensive explanation of how this is done in Java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Slight nit, even with Java 8, it's still only possible with interfaces. What Java 8 gives you is that creating an anonymous class that implements the interface is easier, at the call site. To the function that uses the callback (e.g. `fetchData` above), nothing changes in Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the only equivalent (that I know if) is defining an interface which your `fetchData` method will accept as a parameter, and instantiate an anonymous inner class using that interface. Or, the class calling the `fetchData` method can implement that interface itself and pass its own reference using `this` to method.

This is your method which accepts a "callback":

```
public void fetchData(String url, AjaxCompleteHandler callback){
    // do stuff...
    callback.handleAction(someData);
}
```

The definition of `AjaxCompleteHandler`

```
public interface AjaxCompleteHandler{
    public void handleAction(String someData);
}
```

Anonymous inner class:

```
fetchData(targetUrl, new AjaxCompleteHandler(){
    public void handleAction(String someData){
        // do something with data
    }
});
```

Or, if your class implements `MyCoolInterface`, you can simply call it like so:

```
fetchData(targetUrl, this);
```

Comment: Yes, this is covered in the possible duplicate Q/A.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I didn't notice that until after I posted the answer. My bad.